# JavaScript - Select row is checked but not checking values in row

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I wrote a script to select values in a row. When you select the checkbox at the beginning of the row, the checkboxes of the values in the row are not selected(if the user hits 'submit' from here, it will process the values, but this is confusing to the user). 
[image]

If you unselect the checkbox at the beginning of the row, the checkboxes of the values in the row are selected(if the user hits 'submit' from here, it will not recognize that anything has been selected). This can be very confusing to a user. 
[image]

I'm not very familiar with JavaScript but have gotten this far. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the code I have for the process:

```
echo "<td>" . '<input id="chkRowFiles" type="checkbox" name="file[]" onchange="selectRowFiles(this.checked);" />' . "</td>";

function selectRowFiles(c){
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 

        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
            checkbox.onclick = function() {
                var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                var secondColumn = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
                document.getElementById('chkEFile' + secondColumn.textContent).checked = c;
                document.getElementById('chkFFile' + secondColumn.textContent).checked = c;
                document.getElementById('chkSFile' + secondColumn.textContent).checked = c;
                document.getElementById('chkTFile' + secondColumn.textContent).checked = c;
            };
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing

`echo "<td>" . '<input id="chkRowFiles" type="checkbox" name="file[]" onchange="selectRowFiles(this.checked);" />' . "</td>";`

to

`echo "<td>" . '<input id="chkRowFiles" type="checkbox" name="file[]" onclick="selectRowFiles(this.checked);" />' . "</td>";`

and changing

```
checkbox.onclick = function() {
```

to

```
checkbox.onchange = function() {
```